# oracle sql script access file from mapped drive

Tags: sql, oracle, file

I need to read some large data from a file into a blob field.

With some testing, I managed to do so as long as the file was on the C: drive (ex. Desktop).

However my script that needs this functionality is in a project located on a mapped drive, and the file I want to read is also located there within a different folder.
Whenever I run the script, it returns with file not found error **"ORA-22288: file or LOB operation FILEOPEN failed. The system cannot find the file specified."**. (All examples I've found on the net used some predetermined file paths like /home or similar)

Here's part of the script:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY FILEUPLOADS AS 'X:/Path/To/File';

DECLARE
dest_loc  BLOB := empty_blob();
src_loc   BFILE := BFILENAME('FILEUPLOADS', 'fileToRead.txt');
BEGIN
    DBMS_LOB.OPEN(src_loc, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READONLY);
    DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(lob_loc => dest_loc, cache => true, dur => dbms_lob.session);
    DBMS_LOB.LOADFROMFILE(dest_lob => dest_loc, src_lob => src_loc, amount => DBMS_LOB.getLength(src_loc));
    UPDATE MY_TABLE SET MY_COLUMN = dest_loc WHERE ID = 3;
END;
```

Could someone point out how I can access my file on the mapped drive?
I also should mention that several databases need the same data.

UPDATE: We cannot access the server, so a directory cannot be created and mapped to it. (thanks for those who suggested it though.)

Folder setup:

X:/Path/To/File

X:/Path/To/Script

Comment: Please be clear. Is the `file not found` error an **os error** i.e. the calling file can't find the called script? Or is it a **database error**,  that is the stored procedure can't find the data file?

Comment: Hi, same error I have had in the past (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47990279/file-or-lob-operation-fileopen-failed-when-loading-an-xml-file-into-a-table?noredirect=1#comment82950663_47990279). Unfortunately, I didn't find a solution but I also be interested how to do that.

Comment: you could write your stored procedure to reach out via HTTP to access the file, or build a restful service that allows file uploads via a BLOB and does an insert

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it'll work that way; if it is a mapped drive, create a directory using UNC, such as in this example:

```
create directory slike_4010 as '\\my_server\d$\Home\GIS\slike_4010';
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a directory on your server and then map that directory.

The command would be as :
CREATE [OR REPLACE] DIRECTORY directory_name AS 'path_name'; Path_name would be your operating system directory path.

Check the link below. IT is very well explained:
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_create_directory.htm